# PHP under IIS6 can't open/read file on network

Tags: php, networking, iis-6

I have a simple php script that runs on an IIS 6 2003 server. All the script does is try to open a file on a shared network network location and display its content to the screen. Try as I might I cannot get that to work. I keep getting a "failed to open stream error message". After a lot of reading (I'm on my second week of working at this) I narrow the problem down to being a server configuration problem. I can run the script through the command prompt and it works fine. If I run var_dump(shell_exec('whoami')) It returns "NULL". If I run that same command on the command prompt it returns the current user that is logged in (i.e. me). The task manager reports that the user for w3wp.exe is "NETWORK SERVICE". I'm including the code below although I'm 100% sure the code is not the problem but, some people like to look at code so there it is. How do you configure or make changes on the server so that it allows reading from a network location? Also, the network location I'm trying to access have been setup with all permissions for everybody so that we can solve this one issue.

```
<?php 
    $theFile="\\\\192.168.0.16\\geo\\junk.txt"; #network file does not works
    #$theFile="junk.txt"; #local file works fine
    $handle = fopen($theFile, "r");
    if($handle){
        while (!feof($handle)){
            $buffer = fgets($handle);
            echo $buffer."<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```